# Postfix relay access denied, NOQUEUE: reject

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot

In trying to set up Postfix to use dovecot for SASL (using mysql for virtual_*) I am unable to send email, either through telnet or Outlook, to a domain other than the one that is on the server.  I am able to receive POP3 email just fine.

For SMTP, I am authenticating in Outlook on port 25, using TLS.

**Update (probably important):** I cannot authenticate via telnet.  When I try `auth login` I receive the error `503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled`

I get the error `554 5.7.1 Relay Access Denied`.

I have included below the output of `postconf -n`, please let me know if you need additional information - any help is appreciated!

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = /etc/mailname
myhostname = emaproduction.truckingshow.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = truckingshow.net
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,         reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

This is the output of `doveconf -n`:

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.13.7-x86_64-linode38 x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ext3
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

Comment: @chris-rockwenn and in `/etc/postfix/master.conf` is sasl_auth enabled for smtp TLS? (e.g. `smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes`)

Comment: @mcantsin - yes it is.  It is commented out under the `submission` section

Comment: `submission` would be port 587 then.

Comment: @mcantsin should I have **either** `submission` or `smtps` un-commented? Right now both are.  I tried port 587 and port 465 with TLS - same result (I can send to local domains, not external).

Comment: well, depends what you want. Port 25 ist smtp unencrypted, port 587 submission port (TLS) and port 465 smtps (SMTP-SSL). You can have all three, if you wish.

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær I have just added it.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Can you add the current master.cf aswell? How have you set your clients to auth when sending mail?

Comment: Relevant bits of `mail.log`, `mail.err` or `auth.log` would probably be useful.

Comment: You have `smtpd_tls_auth_only`, so unencrypted authentication is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to port 587 to submit mail and enable TLS.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  I can send to local users with TLS on ports 587 and 465, but still can't relay.

Comment: does your isp block port 25?

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue if they can't get the authentication part of SMTP (to integrate with Dovecot) working.